# ipython : creating Class on the fly

Tags: python, ipython, global

Why this works :

```
In [1]: def new_class(klass):
   ...:    globals()[klass] = type(klass, (object,), {})
   ...:    

In [2]: new_class('AA')

In [3]: AA()
Out[3]: <__main__.AA at 0x7f5629c5ddc0>
```

But when it is from module it doesnt ??

```
In [4]: from maker import *

In [5]: new_class2??
Signature: new_class2(klass)
Docstring: <no docstring>
Source:   
def new_class2(klass):
        globals()[klass] = type(klass, (object,), {})
File:      /my/py38/seq2struct/lib/maker.py
Type:      function

In [6]: new_class2('AB')

In [7]: AB()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 AB()

NameError: name 'AB' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, so the solution is

```
In [10]: import maker

In [11]: maker.AB()
Out[11]: <maker.AB at 0x7f5629bbe370>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problems is that `globals()` returns the dictionary implementing the current module namespace. (see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals))

`new_class2` is defined in a different module, therefore it is modifying the globals of that module.

Comment: This is an important and subtle point.  In Python, there are NO truly global globals.  A global is really only local to the current module.

Comment: thanks ... any idea how to register the new-class also in the current globals ?

Comment: One could pass the `globals` function as a parameter to the other module or even the dictionary returned by `globals`.
For example: `new_class2(globals, 'AB')`
And then use the globals of the calling module like:
`def new_class2(_globals, klass):  \n  _globals()[klass] = type(klass, (object,), {})`